# Unable to execute the SQL queries in Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-studio

I am following the instruction in Microsoft Learn Page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/understand-the-sql-dw-connector-with-azure-databricks/5-create-tables-perform-queries

As I copy and execute the SQL queries in Azure Data Studio, it said it has syntax error

You can refer the code in the above link and the result in the below picture

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1) Are you really trying to create table using `master` database 2) Is it Azure SQL DB/Azure Datawarehouse?

Comment: Hi David Chan, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark(accept) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot and found that if you want to create table in master DB, the user must be the `dbcreator` role.

Reference:[How to fix "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database "master" ?](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8027/how-to-fix-create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master)

But for Azure SQL database and SQL Data Warehouse, the `dbcreator` role is not supported. We can not create table in master db, even with ServerAdmin.

You could reference:

1. [Server-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [Database-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks!!!!! I don't notice I can choose the role in the option bar. Such a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can not create tables in master database. You have to select the data warehouse database.